# Linux Script that takes entries from a CSV file and writes them into a config file freeRADIUS

Tags: linux, csv, ubuntu, freeradius

Hello Stackoverflow community,

currently I am looking to write a Linux script in Ubuntu that does the following:

From a CSV file, that looks like this:

```
Name    Lastname

Peter    Johnson
Deb      Meyers
Frank    Müller
```

it should create entries in another file that look like this:

```
peter.johnson Cleartext-Password := "123"
```

so basically always take the Name and the Lastname, make a "username" out of it and write it in the given format in the destination file.

Also, it should convert ö, ä, ü into oe, ae, ue, and ß into ss, if there are any contained in the user names in the CSV. So Frank Müller would be frank.mueller.

Could anyone tell me how I can accomplish this in a Linux script? Needed for a freeRADIUS project.

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code please

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1):

Without any checks for possible problems such as

```
Herbert André     von Meier
Zoë               Schmidt
```

you may try the following

```
!/usr/bin/perl -w
while (<>) {
   s/[äÄ]/ae/g;
   s/[öÖ]/oe/g;
   s/[üÜ]/ue/g;
   tr/A-Z/a-z/;
   print "$1.$2 Cleartext-Password :=\"123\"\n" if /([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)/;
}
```